# IBOutelt found nil when UICollectionViewCell is load

Tags: ios, swift

I am studying how to create a simple app without storyboard and I have a problem:
I created a XIB called `HomeViewController`, inside it has a `UICollectioView` and made the registration of the cell in the `viewDidLoad()`.
after that, I created a cell called `HomeCollectionViewCell`, put the `identifier` as "cell", in the cell it has a `UILabel`Outlet, that is referenced in the .swift file.
After setting the `delegate` and the `datasource`, it has the mandatory methods of the datasource, when making the cell configuration and calling the label by setting any text it returns nil. I don't know why this is happening, I've seen several videos on YouTube and none has solved the problem. Can anybody help me?

HomeViewController

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

   var info = ["Image"]

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       collectionView.register(HomeCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: 
                               "cell")
       collectionView.delegate = self
       collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
  }

  extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
      func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection 
                          section: Int) -> Int {
       
       return info.count
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: 
                      IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: 
                                                     indexPath) as? HomeCollectionViewCell
       cell?.teste.text = "test"
       return cell!
    
  }


 }
```

HomeCollectionViewCell

```
class HomeCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

   @IBOutlet weak var teste: UILabel!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()
     
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you have to register cell's nib not just class:

```
collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "HomeCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```